# Python won't display greek characters in Apache

Tags: python, apache, encoding, utf-8

I installed python and got it to work with apache. It works normally with english characters but when I'm trying to print something in Greek it prints weird question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be fixed by putting this on the end of apache's httpd.conf file:

```
SetEnv PYTHONIOENCODING utf-8
```

With this Apache will tell Python to use UTF-8 as the default encoding.